# how to find value in list of dictionaries where keys are not consistent

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

here, I have a list of dictionaries, I need to find the object using value.

```
people = [
   {'name': mifta}
   {'name': 'khaled', 'age':30},
   {'name': 'reshad', 'age':31}
]
```

I would like to find by 'age' key where value is 30. I can do this by following way

```
for person in people:
  if person.get('age'):
    if person['age'] == 30:
```

is there any better way to do this without lots of if else?

Comment: you just need to use `if person.get('age') == 30:`, `get` by default returns `None` which is never `== 30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid if..else you can use lambda function.

```
fieldMatch = filter(lambda x: 30 == x.get('age'), people)
```

or also use list comprehension to get names in a list.

```
names = [person['name'] for person in people if person.get('age') == 30]
```

Comment: list comprehension is considered much easier to read than lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `dict.get()` one time without `person['age']`, it allows you to provide a default value if the key is missing, so you can try this:

[dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError

```
people = [
   {'name': 'mifta'},
   {'name': 'khaled', 'age':30},
   {'name': 'reshad', 'age':31}
]    
for person in people:
    if person.get('age',0)==30:
        print(person)
```